# Google Cloud Firestore documents limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I've been working with `Google Cloud Firestore`. I'm about to **import `13000+`** records from a `CSV` to the firestore back-end. I'll be using this collection for **look up** and **auto-completion** purposes.

I'm curious and concerned to know if this is a good idea. Also, I'm looking for some suggestions on what techniques should I be using to make retrieval of this this data as efficient as possible. I'm working with `Angular 5` and using `AngularFire2` to connect with Firestore.

The document itself is really small such as:

```
{
  address: {
    state: "NSW"
    street: "19 XYZ Road"
    suburb: "Darling Point"
  },
  user: {
    name: "ABC",
    company: "Property Management Company"
  }
  file_no: "AB996"
}
```

Most of the searching would be based on `file_no` property of the document.

**Update**

I just imported all 13k+ records to Firestore. It is really efficient. However, I have one issue. After importing the records, I'm getting the message on my Firestore console that my daily limit for Read Operations is reached *(0.05 of 0.05 Million Ops)*. I just wrote data and displayed those records in a Data Table. I used the following query:

```
this.propertyService
      .getSnapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(properties => {
        this.properties = properties;
        this.loadingIndicator = false;
      });


getSnapshotChanges(): Observable < any > {
  return this.afs.collection(this.propertiesCollection).snapshotChanges()
    .map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.payload.doc.data();
        data.id = snapshot.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
}
```

How dos this makes my reading limit exceed?

Comment: That message means that you've passed the (free) quota of document read operations for your Firestore project. If you run your `getSnapshotChanges ` just 4 times, you'll already be over it. Note that this has nothing to do with the scalability of the database or your solution, it is merely the quota you get for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of documents in a collection is of no consequence when you use Cloud Firestore. That's actually one of its bigger perks: no matter how many documents are in a collection, the queries will take the same amount of time.

Say you add 130 document and (for sake of example) it takes 1 second to get 10 documents out of it. That's the performance you'll get no matter how many documents are in the collection. So with 1300 documents it will also take 1 second, with 13K it will take 1 second, and with 13M, it will also take 1 second.

The problem more developers run into is to make their use-cases fit within the API of Firestore. For example: the only way to search for strings is with a so-called prefix match, there is no support for full-text search. This means that you can search for `Prop*` and find `Property Management Company`, but not for `*Man*` to find it.

Comment: In my use case, user enters a file number and I've to auto complete the related details in a form. Should I use indexing? Will it be efficient having thousands of documents in my collection to look up?

Comment: Yes, you can easily look up a document based on its `file_no` field. Although if that value is unique across all documents within the collection, you could also consider using its value as the key of the documents.

Comment: Does it makes any performance difference if its not a key? Thanks.

Comment: Note that all of this is rather broad and generic. The best way to get a feel for whether Cloud Firestore is a good match for your app, is to start working with it. The codelab might be a good place for that: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web